# How do I install Python in Google Cloud Shell?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-shell

I have python 3.5 on my google cloud shell and want 3.7 so I can do command line debugging of code I am going to deploy via google cloud functions (and use 3.7 features such as f-strings).

I have tried various forms of the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python37
```

and always get back

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python37
```

Comment: Did you try `python3.7`?

Comment: Yes - `python3.7` and `python3.7.3` - all with same results

Answer (score 21):

```sh
# install pyenv to install python on persistent home directory
curl https://pyenv.run | bash

# add to path
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc

# updating bashrc
source ~/.bashrc

# install python 3.7.4 and make default
pyenv install 3.7.4
pyenv global 3.7.4

# execute
python
```

This is based on @yungchin answer.

Comment: I had to run a new instance of the shell before running `pyenv`

Comment: @Ali Khosro will this technique work on Colab which actually is 3.6.9 ?

Comment: This should work on any linux environment when you can not (or do not want to) use package manager to install newer version of python.

Comment: it's not working, after 'pyenv global' the global Python is the old one

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me on the GCP shell.

```
# Install requirements
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential checkinstall libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev zlib1g-dev openssl libffi-dev python3-dev python3-setuptools wget 

# Prepare to build
mkdir /tmp/Python37
cd /tmp/Python37

# Pull down Python 3.7, build, and install
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/Python-3.7.0.tar.xz
tar xvf Python-3.7.0.tar.xz
cd /tmp/Python37/Python-3.7.0
./configure
sudo make altinstall
```

Then you would just call Python like so:

`python3.7 ./yourScript.py`

Src: https://serverfault.com/questions/918335/best-way-to-run-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-16-04-which-comes-with-python-3-5

Comment: That worked, thanks. Do you know how I can make a virtualenv with it now?

Answer (score 12):

Even if the packages were available through apt, the downside of using apt would be that you'd have to install all over again whenever you'd been disconnected from Cloud Shell: it always discards your runtime container.

I'd recommend using https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv for convenience. If you follow the installation guide (and note the bash profile additions should go into `.bashrc` in our case) you end up with a python build in your home directory, which is persisted across Cloud Shell sessions. This involves just a few steps:

1. clone the repo into `~/.pyenv`
2. append three lines (see the README) to `.bashrc` to adjust your `$PATH`
3. `pyenv install 3.7.3`  # this takes a while to build
4. `pyenv global 3.7.3`  # sets this version as the default

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 can be installed in Cloud Shell as a side-effect of installing Conda/Anaconda. Copy the link to the desired installer shell script available here: [Installing on Linux](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/linux.html).

### Example

```sh
Welcome to Cloud Shell! Type "help" to get started.
$ wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py39_4.10.3-Linux-x86_64.sh
$ bash Miniconda3-py39_4.10.3-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

After following the instructions, close Cloud Shell and open a new session. Python is now updated.

With Conda installed, you can now create environments for additional Python versions as follows:

```sh
$ conda create -n "py37" python=3.7.0
$ conda activate py37
$ python --version
Python 3.7.0
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that as you can see in your output this installed py3.9.4, not 3.7 as requested.

Comment: Fair enough. But the point of using conda is to be able to use different versions at will.

Comment: @abalter See updated answer showing how to set up environments for different versions of Python after Conda is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple approach is

```
sudo `which conda` install python=3.7 -y
```