# Changing Google Cloud Python Version to Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

I used the command below to upgrade to python3.7
[image]

But when I control the python version, it is still python 2.7.
How should I do?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried answer provided by [harmanw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54347468/12264548)

Comment: when i check the version , it is still 2.7

Comment: I should have typed  python3.7 istead of python :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the instructions provided in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/919064/551540):

> Then you would just call Python like so:
>
> ```
> python3.7 ./yourScript.py
> ```

Do not forget to use `python3.7` instead of `python`.