# Update to python 3.10 in Google Cloud Shell

Tags: python, linux, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I want to upgrade to python 3.10 in my google cloud shell, but I failed to do so. I found two methods online, which were unsuccessful so far.

1. **Using the deadsnakes repo**: I tried the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt update
```

But I get an Error `The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file.`

2. **Install from the source**: I followed the tutorial in [this](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-3-8-on-ubuntu-18-04/) link.
   I am able to install python 3.10. But when my Google Cloud Shell restarts, I am unable to run python3.10. It states `-bash: python3.10: command not found`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked out for me. The default python version remained 3.10.7 even after the shell restarted.

```
# install pyenv to install python on persistent home directory
curl https://pyenv.run | bash

# add to path
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc

# updating bashrc
source ~/.bashrc

# install python 3.10.7 and make default
pyenv install 3.10.7
pyenv global 3.10.7

# execute
python
```

credit to @ali-khorso and @yungchin. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53468831/how-do-i-install-python-in-google-cloud-shell) to the post

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud Shell environment is ephemeral and reset after each session, as an alternative solution you can configure your Google Cloud Shell by creating a Docker image that functions as a custom Cloud Shell environment with your specified additional packages and custom configurations. Refer on this documentation to [Customize Cloud Shell container images](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/customizing-container-image) and [Environment customization.](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/configuring-cloud-shell#environment_customization)

Additionally Google Cloud Shell is running on Debian 11, you can follow this guide on [Installing Python 3.10 On Debian 11.](https://cloudcone.com/docs/article/how-to-install-python-3-10-on-debian-11/)